# how to convert all json files of directory to text files in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert all json files of directory to text files through this command: but I got error. How can I change it?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(r"/media/New Volume/a3d/pdb/json_parser/ *.json ")
df.to_csv(r"/media/New Volume/a3d/pdb/json_parser/ *.txt ", index = False)
```

Comment: What was your error?

Comment: please provide some sample data

Comment: There are spaces around your ` *.txt ` and ` *.json ` - that's probably the problem. Delete those.

Comment: `pd.read_json()` doesn't take globs. Use the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for that. Also, `df.to_csv()` won't understand what `*.txt` means. To break down the problem, focus on just converting one file, then move to looping over all of them and converting each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# Get the list of json files, which are in the folder:   
str_address = r"/media/New Volume/a3d/pdb/json_parser/"
lst_files = [i for i in os.listdir(str_address) if i.endswith(".json")]

# Loop through the json files
for file_ in lst_files: 
    df = pd.read_json(str_address + file_)
    df.to_csv(str_address+ file_+ ".txt", index = False)
```

Comment: you could describe it. And maybe it would be better to use normal `for`-loop to get `os.listdir()` because beginner may not know what you do ;)